# Convert any null or falsy values in an array to blank string "" values Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, google-apps-script

I did an API get request and put the results in an array. Some of the results may come back undefined or null - later in the script I need to pass along the values as strings - so if there is no value I need it to pass along as a "" string value. But how can I loop through the array and make sure that any non-value values are stored as a string with `""`?

```
var dealresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dealurl, options);
  dealresponse = JSON.parse(dealresponse.getContentText());

  var propertyAddress = dealresponse.data["9bd1d8c4f07f5795fd8bffb16f3b63c6547d7d3a"];
  var leadType = dealresponse.data["c4ecbe01c3494d1be52432f4a3194ede3a50c0f8"];  
  var dealType = dealresponse.data["a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e"];
  var dealSource = dealresponse.data["d76fa2d6f8454a51f7d64d981cd9320877bc2ea0"];

var dealArray = [propertyAddress, leadType, dealType, dealSource];  
  Logger.log(dealArray);
```

I'd like to process `dealArray` at the end and just make sure blanks are actual `""` string values. I don't want to delete or remove these values from the object, I just want to convert anything falsy to a string "" (I believe that "" is considered falsy in and of itself)

Comment: do you have other types in the array, like zeros?

Comment: You could change each of `var propertyAddress = dealresponse.data["9bd1d8c4f07f5795fd8bffb16f3b63c6547d7d3a"];` to `var propertyAddress = dealresponse.data["9bd1d8c4f07f5795fd8bffb16f3b63c6547d7d3a"] || "";`.

Comment: I couldn't get any of the array.map functions to work but I did get the script to work by appending `  | | ""` on the end of each line. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is looping throught the array,

```
 var dealArray = [propertyAddress, leadType, dealType, dealSource];
 const result = dealArray.map((deal) => deal ? deal: "");
```

Another approach is, initialize to empty if the value is not present.

```
 var propertyAddress = dealresponse.data["9bd1d8c4f07f5795fd8bffb16f3b63c6547d7d3a"] || '';
  var leadType = dealresponse.data["c4ecbe01c3494d1be52432f4a3194ede3a50c0f8"] || '';  
  var dealType = dealresponse.data["a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e"] || '';
  var dealSource = dealresponse.data["d76fa2d6f8454a51f7d64d981cd9320877bc2ea0"] || '';
  var dealArray = [propertyAddress, leadType, dealType, dealSource];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have no other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)
values than `undefined` or `null`, you could take a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)

```
dealArray = dealArray.map(v => v || '')
```

Otherwise take a  [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
dealArray = dealArray.map(v => v ?? '')
```